# Validating and filtering issues with BackboneJS

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm discovering BackBone JS (it looks pretty awesome, by the way), and I'm experiencing a few problems with both validating models and filtering collections.

First, here is my code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    window.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            id: "?", 
            title: "Default movie title", 
            year: "Unknown", 
            seen: false
        }, 
        initialize: function Movie() {
            this.bind("error", function(model, error) {
                console.log("An error occured --> "+error);
            });
        }, 
        _validate: function(attributes) {
            console.log("Validation function called");
            if(attributes.title == '') {
                return "Title cannot be empty";
            }
            if(attributes.year > new Date().getFullYear()) {
                return "Woops... looks like this movie is a time traveler"
            }
            if(typeof attributes.seen != 'boolean') {
                return "Attribute 'seen' must be a boolean";
            }
        } 
    });
    m1 = new Movie({year: 2012, title: 'My movie', id: 1});
    m1.set({title: '', year: 2042});
});
```

This code is included from an index.html page, which loads jQuery, UnderscoreJS and BackboneJS before.

This code should display an error in the console when trying to set an empty title, but it doesn't, even if the _validate function is called, with the correct `attributes` parameter.
Note that at first I simply named the function `validate`(with no underscore), like I read on a tutorial, but it wasn't called at all when creating or modifying a movie.

Alternatively, I have a collection for my Movie objects, almost empty for now :

```
    window.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Movie, 
        initialize: function Movies() {}
    });
    m1 = new Movie({year: 1998, title: "Worldcup", id: 1});
    m2 = new Movie({year: 1995, title: "1995 movie", id: 2});
    m3 = new Movie({year: 2012, title: "2012", id: 3});
    m4 = new Movie({year: 2008, title: "2008 movie", id: 4});

    movies = new Movies();
    movies.add([m1, m2, m3, m4]);

    console.log("Displaying movies released after 2000 :");
    var recent = movies.filter(function(movie) {
        return movie.get('year') > 2000;
    });
    for(var i in recent) {
        console.log(recent[i].get('title'));
    }
```

The filter function does not return any result (there should be 2). So I tried to `console.log(movie)`in this function, and apparently the movie passed to the callback is always undefined. So I searched on Google and I found many different syntaxes, many of them involving creating a filter function in the collection :

```
/* Returns a 'wrapped object' containing none of the movies it should */
getRecent: function(year) {
    return _(this.filter(function(movie) {
        return movie.get('year') > year;
    }));
}

/* Does not work either : console.log on result gives http://bit.ly/ZvlkNi */
getRecent: function(year) {
    var filtered = this.filter(function(movie) {
        return movie.get('year') > year;
    });
    return new Movies(filtered);
    }

/* Returns an empty array */
getRecent: function(year) {
    return this.filter(function(movie) {
        return movie.get('year') > year;
    });
}
```

I'm getting kind of lost, mainly because there seems to be a lot of different ways to do the same thing, and that none of them seems to work in my case.

Thank you very much for your help!
Christophe.

Comment: if using backbone 1.0.0 try `this.bind("invalid"` instead of `error`

Comment: That was partially that :

« Model validation is now only enforced by default in save — not in set unless the {validate:true} option is passed. Model validation now fires an "invalid" event instead of "error". » (_Backbone.js website, "Upgrading to 1.0"_ » Also, the function must be named _validate_ (no underscore).
Thanks! 1/2 fixed, then. :)

Comment: Looks like renaming method to _validate_ and binding "invalid" event also solved the filter problem. Strange...

Comment: I guess you were messing with the internal structure of Backbone by setting _validate. Was trying your code just now and figured your models didn't have any attributes when created, due to your _validate.